# Not able to set my domain name

Tags: dns, cloudflare, github-pages

I am trying to map my site which is on github pages (tusharmath.github.io) to a particular domain (tusharm.com) using cloudflare name servers.

Its been more than a day and i can still not see view my website on tusharm.com

Steps followed -

1. Added a CNAME file with value tusharm.com in the gh-pages branch on github.
2. Updated name servers on CrazyDomain that were provided by CloudFlare.

Answer (score 0):

tusharm.com  is loading the same content as tusharmath.github.io at this time, which would lead me to believe you were able to fix things here. Did you need to make any further changes to get this working?

p.s. I work for CloudFlare.

Comment: Yeah I was able to fix it finally using cloud flare.